# How to cut mesh by other mesh , this mesh is 2d

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, game-development, mesh

How to cut mesh by other mesh , this mesh is 2d?

[image]

Now I have two mesh , and I want to cut mesh by other.
anyone have idea? and not need quickly just work enough. and don't need care about uv texture. just care about vectices. thanks.

Comment: Polygon intersection algorithms are very complicated (and probably the result of many PD theses). You should just look for a library that does this for you.

Comment: @shingo yes , maybe have libaray to do it?

Comment: @PMF I found this Lib https://github.com/karl-/pb_CSG , but it's for 3d.

Comment: @TimChang One known algorithm is named "GPC" (Generic polygon clipping). If you search github for "gpc polygon" you'll get a bunch of implementations in different languages.